# How do I always mount the same drive to the same location?

Tags: mount, fstab

I have Debian running on a laptop of mine, and an `rsnapshot` config that does a wonderful job of backing up incrementally to a 1TB external drive of mine. Unfortunately, sometimes the drive mounts to `/media/ivy` when I plug it in, other times it's at `/media/usb0`. How can I go about standardizing the mount point? I had initially thought of using `fstab`, but as a novice there, I thought `fstab` usually handled more permanent drive connections--as I want to do this on a laptop, drives frequently come and go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved a similar problem was to ensure the external USB volume was labelled, and then manually mounting and unmounting it using /dev/disk/by-label/labelname  (This is useful if you rotate have multiple disks and a script, and then label disks Backup_01, Backup_02 etc

In order to "Fix" the mounting point to act as you wish to do, you probably need to look to UDEV, which enumerates devices.  Configuring this is a bit of trial and error, but for an installation where I wanted to identify and run a script, I used :

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{product}=="EXTIDPRODUCTIDENTIFUER", ATTRS{serial}=="DEVICE_SERIAL_NO",RUN+="/usr/local/bin/script.to.run"
```

To discover the parameters to pass to udev I issued the command 

udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdXX)

I see no good reason why the script you would execute could not be a mount command.

Comment: it is not clear how to achieve what the OP requested... no clear steps, but a lot of explanation around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with `gvfs-mount` but I can't tell you how. `gvfs-mount` should mount at `/media/YOUR_DRIVE_VOLUME_NAME` by default. As long as your drive has a volume name (I assume it does since it is sometimes mounted at /media/ivy). Anyway, a workaround using `fstab` would be to add an entry using the `UUID` of your external drive.

- To get the UUID of your drive do

  ```
  ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
  ```

  You should see something like

  ```
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 14 16:58 E208CFC0FGG345JDB -> ../../sdb1
  ```
- Assuming your external drive's partition is `/dev/sdb1`, you can add an entry to your `fstab` like so:

  ```
  UUID=C0BCD19CBCD18D72   /media/ivy  ntfs    nofail,defaults 0   0
  ```

Now, according to `man mount`, `nofail` only suppresses error messages. However, according to [this page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114856), it also causes `mountall` to skip non-existing devices. If that doesn't work, you can also try the `bootwait` ([source1](https://askubuntu.com/a/14369/85695), [source2](https://askubuntu.com/a/589/85695)) and/or `bg` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/195677/85695)) options. Unfortunately, I do not have an external drive handy at the moment, so I cannot check.